# "Answerer" and "asker"

Tags: orthography

I just went to post a question on another Stack Exchange site and my spell checker is telling me that *asker* is incorrect but *answerer* is correct.

Is *asker* wrong? What should I use instead?

Comment: Tip: Web browser spellcheckers often have words missing. If in doubt: check a real dictionary.

Comment: @Hugo - Apologies for asking a simple question. I was a bit surprised and since I was already on SE I immediately jumped over here. I can't delete the Q now as it has an answer :( In the future I won't be so rash.

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60179/8278

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Asker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asker)* is listed in Merriam-Webster, as is *[answerer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/answerer)*.