# Should I prefer "asker" or "questioner" for a person who asked a question?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

Should I prefer *asker* or *questioner* for a person who asked a question?

Another [question and answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/47728/11762) on this site give a link that *asker* is quite legitimate. On the other hand I wonder whether *questioner* can be used for any person who asks a question rather than an interrogator.

P.S. The context can be taken as referring to the people who ask questions on this site.

Comment: There's a reason why "[OP](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+OP+mean)" was invented. Because both "questioner" and "asker" sounds *odd*.

Comment: I prefer “asker”, even as it may be less common. Because an asker is someone who asks. A questioner is someone who questions. Those verbs have different meanings: to ask is merely to request (an answer). To question is to put into doubt if not outright deny or refute. “OP” is a bit too slangy for my taste.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT: I have received a lot of commentary on this, enough legitimate commentary that I decided to take a closer look at my answer. The results were mildly surprising to me. See below.

---

Either one has the right meaning and does not really carry bad connotations in my own intuition, although others have commented that **questioner** connotes an interrogation and that they much preferred **asker**.

I found this unusual, since **questioner** is by far the more common word in general English use:

[A Google Ngram query for 'asker, questioner'](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=asker%2C+questioner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) reveals that 'questioner' is found overwhelmingly more often than 'asker'. In addition to the Google Ngram, a query against the [BYU Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) gives the following relative rankings:

> `WORD 1 (W1): ASKER (0.05)`
> `WORD 2 (W2): QUESTIONER (19.53)`

While the British National Corpus query gives:

> `WORD 1 (W1): ASKER (0.01) NONE`
> `WORD 2 (W2): QUESTIONER (90.00)`

At this point, I would've recommended you stick with **questioner** in most cases. And that answer was accepted, but it was not popular, and I wondered why. Dictionaries and thesauri did not show any evidence that either was more or less used, or had any particular connotation. I investigated whether it was a UK-US difference, but found no evidence of that either; the commenters did not have a geographic bias that I could discern.

Then I realized I had the perfect corpus right at hand: Stack Exchange itself! So I ran a search query against all SE sites. And to my surprise:

> `site:stackexchange.com asker` [About 24,600 results](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackexchange.com%20asker)
> `site:stackexchange.com questioner` [About 3,260 results](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackexchange.com%20questioner)

And there you have it. In general English usage across all contexts, **questioner** is favored. But in Internet-based interactive context like that found on this -- a question and answer site -- ***asker*** is used more often by far.

Why is this so? I suspect that is because a query limited to StackExchange also limited the context to a more neutral or descriptive use. Alternatively, it may be that SE users come from a subset of the population -- generational? gender? education? -- that favors **asker** as more neutral.

Since you specifically say, "The context can be taken as referring to the people who ask questions on this site" then I must say that, *contra* my earlier thoughts, **asker** is the answer.

Comment: Does not "questioner" bear the connotation that it is somebody who conducts a questionnaire?

Comment: No, it's fairly neutral.

Comment: @MarkBeadles The problem with your ngram plot is that it provides no context. `Questioner`, at least to me, is someone conducting an interrogation, whereas an `asker` would be someone in a lecture hall audience, or someone conducting a survey. However, that's just my idiolect talking...

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu

Comment: @Mahnax, that meta question is largely irrelevant to simple claims like *questioner* occurring far the more commonly than *asker*.  (The meta question would become completely irrelevant if a "in books published between..." clause were added to claim.)

Comment: @msanford I understand the point about idiolects, but since there are millions of them, the only way we can decide between idiolects is with data. Although the Ngram does not show context, it does show that **questioner** is _overwhelmingly_ more common than **asker** when looking across all contexts.

Comment: @Mahnax Do you have a specific point about this particular Ngram, or are you just saying we shouldn't use Ngrams at all? In this case the Ngram is pretty relevant.

Comment: @jwpat7 I have no particular objection to this use of an NGram. I'm just putting it out there; hence the lack of explanation. By the way, the downvote was not me, in case that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @Mahnax I have added queries against alternate American and British corpora.

Comment: Also: just used an NGram in an answer as supporting evidence.

Comment: The upvotes for msanford's distinction clearly suggest it's widely understood, at least by ELU users. Contextless NGrams tell us nothing about that distinction, and I'd have probably downvoted the original of this answer if it simply said *"both are fine, but **questioner** is more common"*. But I'm looking at it for the first time *post-edit* (and following an inspired choice of research method), and I think this is a truly stellar "canonical answer"!

Comment: I must admit I was totally surprised by some people's (legitimate) objection that they thought "questioner" implied interrogation or conducting a questionnaire. It just doesn't carry that connotation to me at all. So it was worth it to look further. My only remaining doubt is the probability  that SE is not a representative community of native English speakers.

Comment: Don't use Google to determine the number of hits because the numbers will be [inaccurate](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2672285?hl=en). In this case, however, using [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/814498/questioner-vs-asker) to look at one site, Meta Stack Overflow, the numbers are pretty close in proportion: 455 for "questioner", 2080 for "asker".

Comment: @Mark Beadles: "My only remaining doubt is the probability that SE is not a representative community of native English speakers." I was actually quite surprised you didn't follow it up in the answer. That's, indeed, a major factor here. (BTW, as yet another foreigner, I also landed here trying to find out what would be the best alternative to the dreaded "OP", so thanks for the SE stats! ;) )

Answer (score 4):

I think the two words carry different meanings.

An asker is someone who wants to satisfy their need of information, money, services, etc. I would say, the action of asking is usually for the sake of what is asked for. You need to answer what that is.

Questioning, on the other hand, is mainly about information. Moreover, it is to get something more than the expected response. The purpose of a questionnaire, for example, is not merely the answers, but actually to research something else. In addition, the word questioner gives the feeling of power.

> I'm going to ask him

versus.

> I'm going to question him

As a result, I would say, someone who asks a question to know the answer is an asker whilst someone who asks a question for **not mainly** the response itself *(like for testing the answerer)* is a questioner.

Comment: But what about "I'm going to ask him a question"?

Comment: @MarkBeadles I think the last part of the answer answers your question; it depends.

Comment: Don't forget "to be put to the question" and the implications of questioning being forceful, e.g. "the inquisition".

Answer (score 3):

*Asker* doesn’t sound right; *questioner* is ok.

But perhaps the word you are looking for is *querent*, defined by the OED as a person who asks or inquires.

Another applicable word would an *interrogator*, although that somewhat suggests sharp questions.

Lastly, there’s *enquirer*.

Comment: _Querent_ could work, but it seems too formal to really function as a standin for _OP_ here. I think it’s very interesting that you find _questioner_ okay, but not _asker_: it's exactly the reverse in my head. _Questioner_ is too broad and vague: it might just fly on [philosophy.se] where people who ask questions really are people who _question_ things, but on other sites, where a question is usually just a question, I find _asker_ much more natural.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Asker* is growing on me.

Comment: @tchrist, Why not [OP](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60179/should-i-prefer-asker-or-questioner-for-a-person-who-asked-a-question#comment654851_60179)?

Comment: site:stackexchange.com **querent**  About 2,250 results

Answer (score 1):

**Seeker** is [the most-commonly used, per Ngram search](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=asker%2Cquestioner%2Cenquirer%2Csearcher&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), in a comparison between:

1. seeker
2. seacher
3. questioner
4. enquirer
5. asker

(listed by popularity of usage)

*"Researcher"* exceeds all of these usages by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Puzzlingly, _seeker_ seems to have fallen somewhat out of favour around the time the Harry Potter books were first published.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Don't read into it. It's likely just coincidence. HP series didn't really get famous until many years later.