# Is 'answerer' acceptable as a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the common term to refer to  someone who answers a question (written or spoken)?

Is `answerer` a correct term? If so, is it common? If not, what is the correct term to refer to such person?

Comment: *Answerer* is fine. There are a lot of other possibilities depending on context.

Comment: A similar previous question: [“Answerer” and “asker”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47727)